# prase error while boost join during cmake

Tags: c++

I want to develop an UI for ROS platform using Qt. But when I try run cmake in the Catkin workspace the following error appears in the terminal:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/prabin/QT_point/rosqt_ws/build"
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/prabin/QT_point/rosqt_ws /build"
####
[  4%] Generating include/qtros/moc_main_window.cxx
[  9%] Generating include/qdude/moc_qnode.cxx
[ 13%] Generating include/qdude/moc_main_window.cxx
[ 18%] Generating include/qtros/moc_qnode.cxx
```

usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"
qdude/CMakeFiles/qdude.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'qdude/include/qdude/moc_qnode.cxx' failed

Any idea what is the issue?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This error - usr/include/boost/type_traits/detail/has_binary_operator.hp:50: Parse error at "BOOST_JOIN"  occurred for me when I tried to integrate ROS Kinetic into Qt.

It can be resolved by adding  the following 2 lines between the includes in your .h or .hpp files

```
#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN
#endif
```